# Animate this CSS when comes into view

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-animate

I have the following animated line. I have tried several times to add .js to make it where the line animates each time it comes into view on desktop and mobile - and animates only when in viewport/screen. Is this even possible?

```
<div class="tm-scroll">
  <span></span>
</div>
```

```
.tm-scroll {
    position: relative;
    width: 3px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
}

.tm-scroll span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #F6DFA4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    animation: scrollHelperFerro 3s infinite ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes scrollHelperFerro{
  0% {
        transform: translateY(-100%);

  }
   100% {
        transform: translateY(100%);

  },
}
}
```

I tried adding random .js snippets I found via codepen, but I don't know enough about .js to "see" what little thing I have out of place to make it work.

Comment: IntersectionObserver will help you start the animation when the element comes into view (do you want it wholly in view or say only half before the animation starts?) and to remove the animation when the element goes out of view - but specify how much should be seen or not so we can prevent a too-bouncy effect as it goes out at the top of the viewport.

Comment: Great question. I will be using it as a way to lead the user to the next content block in a timeline (vertical) - so they realize there is another timeline info block after what they are currently reading. So, in a perfect world, maybe a small amount of the line would be visible and then the line would animate as it came fully into view. Here is the page I am working on: https://marydbourbon.com/her-story-timeline

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much of the element you want to be in view before the animation starts as to what threshold you set on the IntersectionObserver.

This snippet just demonstrates the idea - starting the animation when at least 50% of the element is in the viewport.

```html
<div class="filler">PLEASE SCROLL DOWN</div>
<div class="tm-scroll">
  <span></span>
</div>
<style>
  .filler {
    height: 150vh;
    background: pink;
  }
  
  .tm-scroll {
    position: relative;
    width: 3px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: auto;
  }
  
  .tm-scroll span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #F6DFA4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    animation: scrollHelperFerro 3s infinite ease-in-out;
  }
  
  @keyframes scrollHelperFerro {
    0% {
      transform: translateY(-100%);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateY(100%);
    }
    ,
  }
</style>
<script>
  let callback = (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        span.style.animationName = 'scrollHelperFerro';
      } else {
        span.style.animationName = 'none';
      }
    });
  };
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {
    threshold: 0.5
  });
  const tmScroll = document.querySelector('.tm-scroll');
  const span = tmScroll.querySelector('span');
  observer.observe(tmScroll);
</script>
```

You may need to think through what you want to happen on a narrow device in landscape mode (when the element will be taller than the viewport).

Comment: This works great! Not to look a gift horse in the mouth, but is it possible to have it animate once in scroll view (not infinite loop), and perhaps reverse as user scrolls up? You are so great! Thank you!

Comment: Replace infinite with 1 and you can learn about reversing an animation e.g. at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-direction